# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" while creating Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using cloudera vm. I have imported the products table from `retail_db` as a `textfile` with `'|'` as a fields separator (using sqoop).

Following is the table schema:

```
mysql> describe products;
product_id: int(11)
product_category_id: int(11)
product_name: varchar(45)
product_description: varchar(255)
product_price: float
product_image: varchar(255)
```

I want to create a Dataframe from this data.

I got no issue while using following code:

```
var products = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/ex/products").map(r => {var p = r.split('|'); (p(0).toInt, p(1).toInt, p(2), p(3), p(4).toFloat, p(5))})
case class Products(productID: Int, productCategory: Int, productName: String, productDescription: String, productPrice: Float, productImage: String)
var productsDF = products.map(r => Products(r._1, r._2, r._3, r._4, r._5, r._6)).toDF()

productsDF.show()
```

But I got `NumberFormatException exception` for following code:

```
case class Products (product_id: Int, product_category_id: Int, product_name: String, product_description: String, product_price: Float, product_image: String)
val productsDF = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/ex/products").map(_.split("|")).map(p => Products(p(0).trim.toInt, p(1).trim.toInt, p(2), p(3), p(4).trim.toFloat, p(5))).toDF()
productsDF.show()
```

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Why is that I am getting exception in 2nd code even though it is same as that of 1st one?

Comment: what does your input looks like ?

Comment: 1009|45|Diamond Fear No Evil Compound Bow Package||599.99|http://images.acmesports.sports/Diamond+Fear+No+Evil+Compound+Bow+Package

1010|46|DBX Vector Series Men's Nylon Life Vest||19.98|http://images.acmesports.sports/DBX+Vector+Series+Men%27s+Nylon+Life+Vest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to `_.split("|")` in second part of your code

You need to use `_.split('|')` or `_.split("\\|")` or `_.split("""\|""")` or `Pattern.quote("|")`

If you use `"|"` it tries to split with regular expression and `|` is or in the regular expression, so it does not matches anything and returns empty string `""`

Hope this helps!